# Bind UUID in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the easiest way to bind a UUID in Spring MVC, such that this works:

```
@RequestMapping("/MyController.myAction.mvc")
@ResponseBody
public String myAction(UUID id, String myParam)...
```

Using the above I currentely get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.UUID]: 
No default constructor found; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.UUID.<init>()
```

There are other questions on SO that skirt around this, but none seem to answer it. I'm using Spring 3.latest (4 EA actually). I'm after the latest, simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: Where is the UUID coming from?

Comment: From an ajax call as a HTTP parameter.

Comment: What's the parameter name?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`UUID` is a class that cannot simply be instantiated. Assuming that it comes as a request parameter you should first annotate the argument with `@RequestParam`.

```
@RequestMapping("/MyController.myAction.mvc")
@ResponseBody
public String myAction(@RequestParam UUID id, String myParam)...
```

Now this expects a request parameter with the name `id` to be available in the request. The parameter will be converted to a `UUID` by the [`StringToUUIDConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToUUIDConverter.java) which is automatically registered by Spring.

---

**Prior to the Spring 3.2**

there was no `StringToUUIDConverter` so additionally you have to write and register converter by your own.

```
public class StringToUUIDConverter implements Converter<String, UUID> {
    public UUID convert(String source) {
        return UUID.fromString(source);
    }
}
```

Hook this class up to the `ConversionService` and you should have UUID conversion for request parameters. (This would also work if it was a request header, basically for everything that taps into the `ConversionService`). You also might want to have a `Converter` for the other-way (UUID -> String).

Hooking it up to Spring MVC is nicely explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-mvc) (assuming you use xml config). But in short:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.company.converter.StringToUUIDConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Incredibly thorough and knowledgable answer. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the version of java being used `fromString` may not be the best way to do this as there are bugs. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8159339

Comment: It looks like spring-framework may not have a work around either. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToUUIDConverter.java#L35

Answer (score 8):

The converter below is available in Spring Framework (core) since version 3.2.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToUUIDConverter<String, java.util.UUID>
```

Comment: do you have to register this converter? out of the box, it does not work.

Comment: yes, take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addFormatters-org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry-

Answer (score 2):

If its coming as a Header parameter use

```
@RequestHeader(value="UUID") String id
```

If its coming in a model

```
@ModelAttribute(value="ModelName") Entity modelName
```