# error 400 when using @modelAttribute on ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use `@ModelAttribute`, but I cannot seem to get past this 400 (Bad Request). I have looked at a ton of SO posts, but none seem to fix what I am seeing.

Here are a few things I've tried:

- reordering parameters on the function
- not having the ("someForm") param on model attribute
- submitting it as a html form instead of spring form

I have tried to simplify this down to the bare minimum before putting it on SO and still cant seem to make it go away. Any ideas?

Here is the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/r/save.spr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveItem(@RequestParam(value = "someId") UUID someId,
                       @ModelAttribute("thisForm") StyleData styleData,
                       BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println();

    return null;
}
```

Here is the model.

```
public class StyleData {

    public String itemId;

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
```

Here is my JSP

```
<form:form id="thisForm" modelAttribute="thisForm">
    <input name="itemId"/>
</form:form>
```

Here is the JS I am using to submit the form.

```
$("#thisForm").submit(function () {
    var str = $("#thisForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: str,
        url: "/r/save.spr?someId=${someId}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            console.log("here")
        },
        error: function(e){
            debugger;
            console.log("fail")
        }
    });

    console.log("Here");
    return false;
});
```

UPDATE 1;
Per the comments I tried the following;

```
$("#thisForm").submit(function () {
    var str = $("#thisForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: str,
        url: "/r/save.spr?someId=${someId}",
        success: function() {
            console.log("here")
        },
        error: function(e){
            debugger;
            console.log("fail")
        }
    });

    console.log("Here");
    return false;
});
```

Update 2:

I was asked what `str` is returning.

```
"itemId=aa"
```

Comment: Model attributes are deserialized from request parameters, but you're seemingly posting JSON.

Comment: Request parameters or JSON? Pick one. For request parameters keep .serialize() and remove dataType: 'json'. For JSON use a JS library like JSON3 + Spring MVC @RequestBody + Jackson library

Comment: so I tried with the ajax call modified stripping out the JSON data type and the json application type still throwing 400.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `str` is returning `"contentItemId=aa"`

Comment: Your handler method is also expecting `someId`. You don't seem to be sending that. See the `@RequestParam` attribute as `required=false`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it is part of the URL.

Comment: There's also no converter, afaik, to convert from a String to a `UUID`. Instead, change the parameter type to `String` and do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366304/bind-uuid-in-spring-mvc).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, we already have UUID conversion wired up.

Comment: Then I suggest setting your log level to DEBUG and seeing what Spring says.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues.

First I suggest you analyze the request/response on both tiers (client and server). For example, if your client is web browser like Chromium or FireFox the developer tools on those browsers expose the request sent to the server and the response details. On the server side, I would use a java debugger and verify first that your method is being reached. You want to make sure your mapping/configuration is correct.

Some details.On the client please verify the url. I question the need for the query string `?someId=${someId} ? You should not need a query string for a post request.

On the server your method signature should be:

```
public String saveItem(@ModelAttribute StyleData styleData, 
      BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
```

Note! You currently have return type of String (that's fine), but you are returning null. If you need to hard code a  value, return a valid path.

One final hint. You can also mock up you client request with Curl.If you try that, you'll find you don't need `; charset=utf-8` in the content type.

Hope that helps.
Please post the result of you analysis :)

Comment: The method is not being reached. OP received a 400 from Spring's `DispatcherServlet`. Maybe OP _does_ need the query string. Why should the method signature be that way? It's an AJAX request, maybe OP doesn't want to return a response body. `null` is appropriate in that case.

Comment: I put the null because I have not finished implementing, since I am not even getting into the method there is no point in having a valid return at this point.  Also I have verified that the ID is being passed.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. Can you post what the web browser is sending in the post request. Can you capture the data. Next on the server why not add a simple method that responds to a "get" request (no parms). That should help verify if you have a controller config or web.xml issue. Use a web browser or Curl to test the get request. Make sure that server path is correct. Good Luck.

Comment: Another question. ".spr". Is that a mime type? Do you need it. Is it defined in your servlet config?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this was due to me missing the application context on the URL. Hate that it was only throwing a 400 on this instead of something more useful.

Comment: So your client was making a request to the wrong url? Can you post the   status? Is this now closed? Question answered :) Code works?

Comment: 400 errors are tricky with Spring MVC. They seem to only be logged at debug level.