# postgresql exception operator does not exist: uuid = bytea

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, uuid

Hi in my spring boot postgresql app i want to execute the below sql query.

```
 SELECT
                o.id as projectId,
                o.name as projectName,
                stld.name || ' ' || pe.firstname || ' ' || COALESCE(pe.middlename , ' ') || ' ' || pe.lastname as employeeName,
                pemp.description as description,
                pemp.actualstartdate as actualStartDate,
                pemp.actualenddate as actualEndDate
            FROM Con_project o
                LEFT JOIN con_project_employee pemp on o.id = pemp.projectid
                LEFT JOIN employee pe on pemp.employeeid = pe.id
                LEFT JOIN system_type_lookup_data stld on stld.id=pe.TITLEID
            WHERE  
                pemp.employeeid = :employeeId  OR pemp.projectid = 
               :projectId
```

**controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeproject", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public Page listEmployeeProject(@RequestParam UUID projectId, @RequestParam UUID employeeId, @RequestParam Integer page, @RequestParam Integer size) {
       profileService.findEmployeeProject(projectId, employeeId, new PageRequest(page, size));
        return null;
    }
```

When i execute the query i'm getting below error. The controller will not have employeeId and projectId in that cast i need to fetch employee project without any filter.

```
.14:15:07.156 [http-nio-6062-exec-9] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883 
.14:15:07.156 [http-nio-6062-exec-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**DDLs**

```
     CREATE TABLE employee
    (
      id uuid NOT NULL,
      createdby uuid NOT NULL,
      createddatetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
      entity_status integer,
      updatedby uuid,
      updateddatetime timestamp without time zone,
      version bigint,
      age integer,
      code character varying(50),
      dob timestamp without time zone,
      email character varying(255),
      firstname character varying(300),
      lastname character varying(300),
      middlename character varying(300),
      mobile character varying(255),
      employee_id character varying(255),
      joined_date timestamp without time zone,
      qualification character varying(255),
      orgid uuid,
      genderid uuid,
      maritalstatusid uuid,
      nationalityid uuid,
      titleid uuid,
      CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),    
      CONSTRAINT uk_nbyivu8qgmx0r7wtbplf01gf8 UNIQUE (code)
    );
    CREATE TABLE con_project
    (
      id uuid NOT NULL,
      createdby uuid NOT NULL,
      createddatetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
      entity_status integer,
      updatedby uuid,
      updateddatetime timestamp without time zone,
      version bigint,
      code character varying(255),
      description character varying(250),
      name character varying(100),
      actualenddate timestamp without time zone,
      actualstartdate timestamp without time zone,
      plannedenddate timestamp without time zone,
      plannedstartdate timestamp without time zone,
      projectvalue double precision,
      orgid uuid,
      customerid uuid,
      projectmgr uuid,
      CONSTRAINT con_project_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT fklhj0vjp9kg5ailryr38s8kbvr FOREIGN KEY (projectmgr)
          REFERENCES public.employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    );

CREATE TABLE con_project_employee
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  createdby uuid NOT NULL,
  createddatetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  entity_status integer,
  updatedby uuid,
  updateddatetime timestamp without time zone,
  version bigint,
  actualenddate timestamp without time zone,
  actualstartdate timestamp without time zone,
  description character varying(255),
  orgid uuid,
  employeeid uuid,
  projectid uuid,
  projectempstatus uuid,
  CONSTRAINT con_project_employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk2dwlm099cuqdy0aoqh8xnxijs FOREIGN KEY (employeeid)
      REFERENCES public.employee (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fkj2my042i5v8kk3h4qq96m2cl1 FOREIGN KEY (projectid)
      REFERENCES public.con_project (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind UUID in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366304/bind-uuid-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: No its not duplicate.

Comment: Well are your UUIDs being correctly mapped when they hit the controller?  This seems non trivial to me.

Comment: its been called by the service method only.

Comment: Fine, but then can you highlight the exact place where the error happens in Postgres/Java ?

Comment: if u observe the stack trace , the exceptions are from postgres.

Comment: could you please share all four tables DDLs?.

Comment: @VaoTsun code updated

Comment: @boycod3 cant reproduce with your given DDLs and statement, please create a structure on sqlfiddle or alike

Comment: There is no table `con_project_employee` in your DDL.

Comment: @VaoTsun DDL updated.

Comment: `select 1 from con_project_employee pemp where employeeid = decode(:employeeId, 'base64') ` try if this works?..

Answer (score 4):

PG is telling you that the SQL is not valid when either `projectId` or `employeeId` is `null`.